# avoid generating a jaxb enum class for this simpleType...(or use string instead)

Tags: jaxb

We have a 10,000 enum that someone put in the xsd which generates a 60,000 line file in java which can't compile saying the code is too large

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project framework: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /Users/dhiller/Space/ifp-core/framework/target/generated-sources/com/framework/util/LanguageCodeSimpleType.java:[7627,4] code too large
```

Anyway in jaxb to either

1. Map the simpletype to a String to generate strings all over the place
2. just exclude the element as I don't think people are using it

(I may just remove it from the schema  and see if people complain or not)

Answer (score 0):

This could help - the enum class is not generated any more.

```
<jaxb:typesafeEnumClass map="false" />
```

[How to avoid mapping to enum class](https://jaxb.java.net/guide/Avoid_strong_databinding.html#Avoid_mapping_to_enum)